# How to add speech bubbles around messages in textview ? Can I use just a text view to initiate a chat interface?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am a relatively amateur coder and have been learning android programming step by step.
I have a doubt regarding the now popular speech bubble around messages that are exchanged over messages.

I have been trying to make a chat interface and with trial and error came up with something like this.

The code to the chat window looks like this:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ranklabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
    android:text="@string/countrylabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:text="@string/populationlabel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/population"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/country"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reply"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/replyMsg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Reply to the user here..."
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="160" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/replyMsg"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
    android:text="GO"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msgView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/replyMsg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/population"
    android:maxLines = "1999"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical" />
```

**JAVA**

```
    final EditText reply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reply);
        final TextView msgView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgView);
        Button replyMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replyMsg);
        msgView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        replyMsg.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                msgView.append("\n>   " + reply.getText());
            }
```

This is the code for thus displaying the messages in the text view appended with a /n to display every sentence that has been typed in the reply window.

I need your help to allow for displaying messages in a chat window instead of looking something like this :

"*>hello there*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can customize a drawable shape and assign it to the textView with some corners maybe

tvBackGround.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorFour" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorTwo"
    android:width="2dp" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
```

and in your java

```
msgView.setBackground(R.drawable.tvBackGround)
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, should the set background go into my void onClick ? or about the void onClick ? Moreover will each message then be displayed with a bubble ?

Comment: if you want to set it always to use the background, you can simply do it in the main xml : android:background="@drawable/tvBackGround"

Comment: No no, I meant the command "msgView.setBackground(R.drawable.tvBackGround)"
should it go into my public void onClick ? or should I type it right under "msgView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());"

Answer (score 1):

The code should go into `onCreate()`. If you are running this on an activity and then go into `onCreateView()`,  if you are running it on a fragment